# Tensorflow + Pytorch install Cudatoolkit 11.2

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I have a Windows 10 machine with an nvidia 3080 card. 11.2 with CudaToolkit
I want to install a Pytorch in addition to TensorFlow, which works 100% fine so far.

If I understand the description correctly, the CudaToolkit installed without the Cuda Python env is “independent” of the Cuda toolkit version installed for Windows.

I tried to install Pytorch with this command, but it does not want to recognize the GPU.

pip install torch==1.9.0+cu102 torchvision==0.10.0+cu102 torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Comment: I think you install the torch with Cuda 10.2. You should try `torch-1.9.0+cu11` and `torchvision-0.10.0+cu111` and the same as audio.